# Crossing sub domain ajax calls

Tags: api, rest, jquery, jsonp

We wish to build a web app that will consume our REST API and looking for a way to circumvent the Same Origin Policy security feature.

We have a REST API which is served from api.ourdomain.com from SERVER_1.
We have a Web App which is server from dashboard.ourdomain.com from SERVER_2.

The Web App communicates with the REST API using ajax calls that include GET, POST, DELETE and PUT requests.

At some point in the future, we might consider allowing 3rd party sites to access the API from their own sites and domains.

Due to the Same Origin Policy security feature of the browsers, these requests are not allowed.

We are looking for ways to circumvent this.

Solutions we have encountered:

1. Tunneling the requests through our proxy. This will slow down the app and requires more resources.
2. JSONP - Will only work for GET requests. We do not wish to overload the GET requests with post/put/delete capabilities.
3. Using an iFrame with document.domain set to the same domain. Will only work for sites under ourdomain.com.
4. Frameworks such as EasyXDM. Seems like a good solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know EasyXDM but I have the same architecture you are talking about in more than one application. We use your suggested solution (1). In my opinion proxying the requests through a common subdomain is the cleanest solution. I don't think that this is a performance problem. Many sites use something like [nginx](http://nginx.org/) anyway to do some sort of reverse proxy (as cache). You could easily tunneling your API through http://[yourhost]/api and the rest of the HTML, CSS and image resources through other paths.